# Cannot query MySQL DB using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

My code is very simple:

```
 $con1 = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=users_db", "root", "");
 $resp = $con1 -> query('SELECT * FROM records');
```

The response I get inside `$resp` is the query string `'SELECT * FROM records'` no clue why.
The same query is working using mysqli.

I tried debugging and I see a strange value `{POD}[0]` in `$con1` after creating the PDO instance.
What am I doing wrong here I followed this [phpro.org](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php

// Connect to MySQL via PDO
try {
$con1 = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=users_db", "root", "");
$con1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

try {
$resp = $con1 -> query('SELECT * FROM records');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

You will get a Exception when the connection fails or when the query fails.

Comment: I did that still no exception and no result I get inside `$resp` the value `'SELECT * FROM records'` after execution of line `$resp = $con1 -> query('SELECT * FROM records');`  and no exceptions at all

Comment: Add also this line: `ini_set('display_errors', true);` now there should be a error.

Comment: Still noting after I add this line, I don't think there is an error

Comment: Didn't help I think the problem is starting when I start the connection in the debug I see `{POD}[0]` inside `$con1`

Comment: +1 For the record this works correctly, you may want to add in the loop example such as `foreach($resp as $row) { var_dump($row); }`

Comment: You are right it is not showing the response inside `$resp` you must extract it